# create view in mvc base tow table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult product_list()
{
    using(myDatabaseEntities1 d=new myDatabaseEntities1())
    {
        var a = (from g in d.departments
                 from p in d.Tables
                 where p.userid == g.kod_achrai
                 select new  { department_name = g.department_name, oved_achrai = p.fullname, teur = g.teur });

            return View(a);
    }            
}
```

The select statement base on 2 tables,
I want to show this in view.
I create a view but i dont know what to put in title
exp: `@model MvcApplication4.department`

I attach picture of option:
[image]

Can someone help me :)
Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"don't now what to put in title"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do scaffolding , so You have to create a model class for it. like

```
   public class deptModel
   {
     public string department_name { get; set; }
     public string oved_achrai { get; set; }
     public string teur { get; set; }
   }
```

and in your code write this

```
    public ActionResult product_list()
     {
    using(myDatabaseEntities1 d=new myDatabaseEntities1())
    {
       var a = (from g in d.departments
                 from p in d.Tables
                 where p.userid == g.kod_achrai
                select new deptModel { department_name = g.department_name, oved_achrai = p.fullname, teur = g.teur });


           return View(a);
        }

    }
```

And thin in this model class list you will find **deptModel** ,to use/select.

and for using two tables yo can use join if you want like this.

```
    var a = (from g in d.departments
                join p in d.Tables
                 on p.userid equals g.kod_achrai
                select new  deptModel{ department_name = g.department_name, oved_achrai = p.fullname, teur = g.teur });
```

and whatever you meant by title exp will be   **@model MvcApplication4.deptModel**

you can use scaffolding template like this in your solution
[image]

hope it will help you

Comment: @chananafcha please add the error in comment section.

Comment: @chananafcha in view try using `@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.deptModel>`  instead of `@model MvcApplication4.Models.deptModel`

Comment: i  add and get this error 
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.deptModel>' does not contain a definition for 'department_name' and no extension method 'department_name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.deptModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you tell me how yo created the view. As i think after watching your view changes . you User `Model` instead of  `model`. I suggest you to first create a view using scaffolding.

Comment: please check how to use scaffolding template , i have edited the answer for that.

Comment: thank- now i use list like yor exmp i get error: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: is there any if else in your `product_list` method, or you are returning from out of the `Using block`?

Comment: i add to_list  to the query.   its work thank you vey much